# CSS question how to make one div appear over another?

Tags: css

i want my div of menu to appear on the top left of the div for my header image. The backgrounds used for the menu blocks are transparent and translucent and i want that the image of the header should be visible under through translucent and transparent backgrounds.. How can i do it using css??
the class for div of menu is divmenu and for header is divmainimg

Comment: And what's your mark-up (html)? And your actual CSS? Could you post a demo to reproduce your set-up at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so's we can see what you're working with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
div.divmainimg {
    position: relative;
}

div.divmenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Consider changing the class names to `mainimg` and `menu`, respectively.

Comment: This is only correct if all div.divmenu objects are nested within div.divmainimg.

Comment: @Ola that is a valid point. This was an assumption I made when answering the question, since no example markup was given in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Set position: relative; on the parent object of your menus that you want them to be positioned relative to, and set position: absolute; on the menu divs. Often you can get away without specifying the exact position - if the divs appear in the DOM where you want them to be visually. E.g. this *could* be enough:

body {
position: relative;
}

div.menu {
position: absolute;
}

Edit: Forget about z-index for now - it is rarely needed.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

try to use absolute position, and set a high z-index for the div you want over others..

Comment: Z-index is rarely needed if the HTML structure is done right; i.e. the topmost object comes after the objects it overlays in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You could also now Just simply put the div you want to be over the other div inside the div you want to be under for example:

pretend your div class="a" is the one you want on top, Then div class="b" you want on bottom.

that would put A on top then B under it.

Answer (score -2):

I believe what you are wanting is `z-index`. Rather than explaining it here, just do a Google search for it. It is simple to understand.

Comment: so i found what z index is question now is that will i add the z index property in the class for the header in this case .divmainimg?

Comment: Likely you will add it to whatever element you want to be ABOVE the others (.i.e. the menu div). Something like `.divmenu {z-index: 999;}` or whatever.